# Unable to size JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I am attempting to add a button to my JFrame. 
I am unable to assign the JButton to a certain size.

I have tried

```
mJButtonOne.setPreferredSize
mjButtonOne.setMinimum/maximum
mjBUttonOne.setSize
```

No matter what I try the button always loads full screen.

Here is my code I am using a few methods, a make, a build, and a dostuff.

```
private void make() {
    this.mJLabelTime = new JLabel("");
    this.mJButtonOne = new JButton("");
//I have tried setting size in do stuff as well.

      }

private void build(){
    this.add(this.mJLabelTime);
    this.add(this.mJButtonOne);

     }

private void doStuff(){

    this.mJLabelTime.setText(Customtime.time("HH:mm:ss"));
    this.mJButtonOne.setText("BUTTON!");
    this.mJButtonOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1, 10));
```

My Main looks like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    View view = new View();
       view.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
       view.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    view.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("Running app..."); 
//System.out.println("Goodbye World");    
}
```

Comment: Are you using `GridLayout`???

Comment: @harper89, are you placing these components directly on the frame?

Comment: @little as in drag and drop? no

Comment: @harper89, no, as in are you adding these components to a `JPanel`, and then adding the panel to the `JFrame`?

Comment: @harper89, therein lies your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using any LayoutManager, call `setLayout(null)` for your `View` class.

But it's recommended that you pick and use a layout manager and let the layoutmanager take care of sizing components.

Comment: why would you ever recommend using a null layout?

Comment: @little that's not what I recommend. `setLayout(null)` is to be able to size components manually but my recommendation wat to use a layout manager.

Comment: my point is, why even include that little bit at the beginning?

Comment: because a good answer covers everything. Thanks Bala this opens things up for me.

Comment: @harper89, I sure hope you didn't use a null layout manager because that is a terrible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the layout manager respects the dimensions you pass to [`setPreferredSize(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29).

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class View {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        };
        final JButton button = new JButton("Button"){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(100, 20);
            }
        };
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT**

Instead of adding the components directly to the `JFrame`, add them to a `JPanel`, and then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`. Note that `JPanel` defaults to a *flow layout*.

Comment: nitpicking: a) LayoutManagers are free to do whatever they like - respect sizing hints or not (the "usually" bit accounts for that, though :-). b) Hard-coding sizes is nearly always the-wrong-thing, doing so in a method override is only marginally better than doing in setXXSize

Comment: @kleopatra, completely agree. :)